# declaration order in let-bindings, Haskell vs OCaml

Tags: haskell, ocaml

In Haskell, declaration order in let/where constructs does not matter, for example:

```
f x = let g1 x y = if x>y then show x else g2 y x
          g2 p q = g1 q p
      in ...
```

where `g2` used in `g1` before its declaration.
But this is not a case in Ocaml:

```
# let a = b in
  let b = 5 in
  a;;
Warning 26: unused variable b.
Error: Unbound value b
```

Is there a reason why OCaml doesn't behave like Haskell? In the absence of forward declaration, this feature seems useful to me.

Is it because of strict evaluation in OCaml but lazy in Haskell?

Comment: Note that in Haskell, the direct translation `let a = b in let b = 5 in a` is still illegal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the strictness as such, but that's a symptom of the same problem.

Ocaml is not purely functional, which is to say that arbitrary function calls can do arbitrary I/O. This requires them to run in a predictable order, which requires both strictness and the let-ordering you've noticed.

Comment: I could hardly imagine a more inaccurate, biased and off-topic answer. The OP is asking about *scoping rules* here, which are an own topic that can be discussed independently of any evaluation order consideration. Besides, there are valid reasons to be restrictive in simultaneous binding scoping even in pure lazy languages, eg. if you want to allow shadowing of previously defined identifiers.

Answer (score 21):

OCaml uses "let rec" to indicate when the binding in a group can refer to each other.  Without the extra "rec" the binding must be in top-down order.  See "local definitions" at http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html for details.

Answer (score 5):

In Haskell it's not because of lazy evaluation. Figuring out which name refers to what happens at compile time, when anyway nothing is being executed (strictly or lazily). Remember in Haskell you're only writing mathematical definitions, not commands to be executed in order. In what order you write these definitions does not matter. Whether you say

```
a = expr1
b = expr2
```

or

```
b = expr2
a = expr1
```

it means that `a` is defined to be `expr1` and `b` is defined to be `expr2`.

I don't know any OCaml, so can't say anything about that.

Answer (score -1):

Haskell did away with the archaic `let` vs. `let rec` distinction.
A decent compiler can see very well if it's a simple let or one that contains mutually recursive definitions and can act accordingly.

(I wonder what a ML compiler does if one starts with `let rec` and then only has non recursive definitions. Surely, this let/let rec thing is a nasty obstacle when one does some refactoring.)

Comment: I miss being able to do `let x = x + 1`, though.

Comment: You can write `let rec` anywhere you want.  The compiler will not complain.  The benefit of `let` is that allows you to be sure that what you are defining does not result in an accidental loop, e.g: `let x = x + 1` as missingo suggested.

Comment: sometimes people like being able to define a new variable inside a scope with the same name as (and hiding) an existing variable outside, set to some transformation of the old variable. automatic `let rec` would prevent this.

Comment: -1 as other comments have pointed out, this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @JonHarrop What is incorrect? That Haskell did away with this?

Comment: @missingno What's wrong with `x = x + 1`? How abut `let (+) = flip (:); x = x + 1 in take 10 x` then? This is perfectly legal and x will be a list of as many 1's as one needs.

Comment: @Ingo: You are thinking too much into this. Its anoying that you have to use a hack like `(\x -> ...)(x+1)` if you want to bind an inner x to a value that depends on the outer x.

Comment: @missingno Beg your pardon, but is that not a bit of a bad excuse, even a mis-use of this language construct? I mean, it's simply not the case that we're running out on names, even on short ones. But if you insist that everything be named `x` you can still `let y = ... x ... in let x = ... y ... in .... x ....`. Already, in Haskell it is irritating that one can write `[x | x <- x, x <- x, x <- x]`

Comment: I find shadowing variables suseful sometimes when I am updating a "state" variable, since doing so protects me from accidentaly misusing the old version. And I concur that the lambda hack is definitly very ugly - I was just pointing out a way to implement a non-letrec "let" in Haskell.

Comment: The distinction is by no means "archaic", and, in certain settings, it can make a world of difference. For example, in a strict language with linear types, `let x1 = e1 and x2 = e2 and ...` is a multiplicative conjunction (all the `xi`s have to be used exactly once), whereas `let rec f1 x1 = e1 and f2 x2 = e2 and ...` is an additive conjunction (exactly one of the `xi`'s has to be used exactly once).

Comment: The reason why Haskell can do away with the distinction between `let` and `let rec` is that, because it has a non-strict evaluation strategy, it can afford to make everything implicitly recursive, and let the implicit mutation introduced by laziness handle any cycles. Languages with a strict evaluation strategy simply do not have this luxury, which is why, for example, Standard ML has a rule that says that the right-hand side of a `val rec` binding must be of the form `fn x => ...`.